# Successfully installed Ubuntu 12.04 getting black screen when starting...

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I just installed ubuntu 12.04.  After it says that it was successfully installed I went on try to launch Ubuntu and I am stuck in a reddish black screen with a black box on the upper left corner. I reinstalled three times, same thing happens. Checked the hardware requirements and I seem to have them but it looks like I got a graphics Card issue.

Single core AMD
Built in VGA (NVIDIA)
320hdd
1GB RAM